# How to conditionally disable <select> from tag helper?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

My goal is to *conditionally* disable a drop-down depending on the status of the model object passed to the view.

The following code correctly renders a disabled `<select>` tag (but not conditionally):

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@priorityList" disabled></select>
```

The following does not.  The attribute `disabled` does not appear in the page source for the rendered page:

```
@{ string disabled = Model.CaseMode == Mode.Active ? "" : "disabled"; }
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@priorityList" @disabled></select>
```

Also, the following also does not disable the `<select>` tag.

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@priorityList" @((Model.CaseMode == Mode.Closed) ? "disabled" : "")></select>
```

I assume the issue has to do with the tag helper processing the `<select>` tag before the string substitution is done in the template.  Can anyone suggest how I can conditionally disable this element without have to render two separate elements in an `if else` structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible with the default `select` tag helper, but you can create your own, and configure it to react to a custom `asp-disabled` attribute, that accepts a boolean.

In your view:

```html
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@priorityList" asp-disabled="@(Model.CaseMode == Mode.Closed)"></select>
```

Then, create your `TagHelper` class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System;

namespace YourNamespace.TagHelpers
{
    // Triggered on all select elements with the asp-disabled attribute
    [HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = DisabledAttributeName)]
    public class SelectTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string DisabledAttributeName = "asp-disabled";

        /// Get the value of the condition
        [HtmlAttributeName(DisabledAttributeName)]
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            if (output == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

            if (Disabled)
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("disabled", null);
        }
    }
}
```

To ensure your TagHelper is used, you'll also need to register it in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```html
@addTagHelper *, YourNamespace
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is additive to the existing `<select>` tag helper that is supplied with the framework, I assume?

Comment: Yes, it's additive. Note that you can change the order in which the tag helpers are called, by overloading the Order property (lower is executed earlier), but it's not required here because there's no collision.

Comment: Thanks, I built a modified version that allows me to pass an enum of Active, ReadOnly or Disabled.  When I created the `Process` method Studio included a call to `base(context, output)`.  Do you know if that's strictly required?

Comment: Actually, I circled back and re-wrote the tag helper to render the `<select>` as a readonly `<input>` instead (to avoid the no-post-back problem).

Answer (score 25):

No need to create custom TagHelper. Try this.

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@priorityList" disabled="@(true)"></select>
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@priorityList" disabled="@(false)"></select>
```

This render:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Priority" name="Priority" disabled="disabled">...</select>
<select class="form-control" id="Priority" name="Priority">...</select>
```

I realized it from here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7333#issuecomment-363504164

Comment: That's indeed much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, much simpler.  I don't think I like it -- it believe it should render `disabled="true"` and `disabled="false"`.  But, I guess that's what we're expected to do.

Comment: `disabled="false"` doesn't make the select enabled. That's why `disabled="@(true)"` doesn't work.

Comment: @Ratul is correct. the html disabled attribute doesn't have a =true or =false. In fact, if you use <select disabled="false".../> it will still show up as disabled because all it looks for is for disabled attribute

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution!

Answer (score 4):

Since disabled="false" didn't work for me and didn't want to add an extension class for just one select list... here's how I solved it:

```
@{ string disabled = Model.CaseMode == Mode.Active ? "disabled" : null; }
<select  asp-for="Priority" class="form-control" disabled="@disabled" asp-items="@priorityList"></select>
```

Another posible solution would be to have your condition in a ViewData dictionary and evaluate once document has been loaded:

```
@if((bool)ViewData["YourModelCondition"]){
     $('#selectListID').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Note: You will need to specify an ID for the select if you use the second solution.